# Can not load 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1' from assembly 'mscorlib c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to write a C# encryption that does not use any external downloads and should work on windows 10 but I get this weird error

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey.AesOperation.EncryptString(String b_key, String plainText)
   at main.start.Main()
```

This is the function that is breaking it

```cs
namespace EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey  
{  
    public class AesOperation  
    {  
    public static string EncryptString(string b_key, string plainText)
    {
        byte[] array;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(b_key);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Adding aes.IV to the stream's start.
                memoryStream.Write(aes.IV);
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        // The final encrypted outcome will be aes.IV+encryptedtext.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string key, string cipherText)
    {
        //input is iv+encrypted text, convert them to byte array.
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // byte array for iv
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        // byte array for rest of the cipher text.
        byte[] cipherBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length - 16];

        // copy first 16 bytes from the cipher text to iv.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, iv, 0, 16);


        // copy rest of the cipher text to the cipher buffer to be decrypted.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 16, cipherBuffer, 0, buffer.Length - 16);

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            aes.IV = iv;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBuffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

How do I fixed this, I am trying to make no downloads and should work on a base windows 10 system any ideas?

NOTE: I am compiling using mono mcs ubuntu and must work while using this

NOTE2: I am importing a DLL doing this

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


        static void Main()
        {
            IntPtr h = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
                    ShowWindow(h, 0);
            for (;;)
```

Comment: You seem to be running Linux/Ubuntu under Windows 10. Probably this is a problem of this particular constellation, because neither under Windows 10 alone nor under Ubuntu/Mono I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user9014097 The decryption works but the encryption doesnt. I am only running ubuntu, not windows. Ubuntu is main OS I am trying to make this work for a default windows 10 install that I am using in a virtual machine but the encrpytion is breaking and I do not know why, Ive tried different virtual machines and still the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what could be causing the error. The code seems to be fine. And as I said, it runs on a Windows 10 machine (as well as on an Ubuntu/Mono machine). Since you have already installed it several times (with different VMs) it should not be an installation problem. Then it must be your constellation: Ubuntu with Windows 10 in a VM (although this does not seem unusual to me and should actually work).